# Join ORC parts and create CSV

Tags: hdfs, orc

What is the simplest way to convert an existing ORC store in many parts on HDFS to one CSV file? I can use hive and/or spark, but I want to keep the memory requirements small, so I don't want to `spark.read` and coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try to export from hive the ORC to an external table in CSV format, setting hive.merge.mapredfiles=true
(https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/92415/how-to-merge-reduce-task-output-to-produce-final-o.html)